# The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm , and node module is not installing

Tags: node.js, npm

I downloaded the project from the internet, when I tried to install the node module, It threw the following

````
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for npm@0.1.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bhar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-08T18_02_29_482Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\bhar\Downloads\tryDo\trydo-template\trydo> npm install -g npm@"0.1.0"
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for npm@0.1.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bhar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-08T18_02_58_538Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Its looking for npm@0.1.0, so try installing that with command npm install -g npm@"0.1.0". This command is there in your log

Comment: it throwing again this error   ```PS C:\Users\bhar\Downloads\tryDo\trydo-template\trydo> npm install -g npm@"0.1.0"
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for npm@0.1.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bhar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-09T04_07_06_384Z-debug.log```

Comment: Try removing package-lock.json and then run npm install and npm update, it will install the latest version. There maybe other dependencies which expecting other version. Share the complete log if you still get error.